# Android - AWS iot connect using MQTT websocket - with customAuthorizer

Tags: android, aws-sdk, mqtt

ios - able to connect with MQTT websocket with customAuthorizer
iotDataManager.connectUsingWebSocket(withClientId: clientId, cleanSession: true, customAuthorizerName: IoTCustomAuthorizerName, tokenKeyName: IoTCustomAuthorizerTokenKeyName, tokenValue: tokenValue!, tokenSignature: tokenSignature!, statusCallback: mqttEventCallback)

but in Android there is no such way to pass these values to AWSIotMqttManager.
connect method only takes credentialsProvider and callback

Is there a way to set all these values